# latex tabular width the same as the textwidth

Tags: latex

I am generating some table as follow:

```
\begin{tabular}[l]{|l|l|l|}
\hline
Input & Output& Action return \\
\hline
\hline
DNF &  simulation & jsp\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
```

How can can I give this table the same width as the text width?
For graphic I use

> [width=\textwidth]

But this doesn't work for table.

Comment: It might be better to move this to tex.stackexchange.com.

Comment: flagged for migration to tex.SX

Comment: Cross-posted: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56492

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `tabularx` package gives you

1. the total width as a first parameter, and
2. a new column type `X`, all `X` columns will grow to fill up the total width.

For your example:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
% ...    
\begin{document}
% ...

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
Input & Output& Action return \\
\hline
\hline
DNF &  simulation & jsp\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to center the text in the X columns?

Comment: @JohnThreepwood and anyone that came upon this page looking for this same question, the following topic on tex stackexchange proved very helpful; https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89166/centering-in-tabularx-and-x-columns

Comment: @WalterB hey, thank you for the answer of my old comment :-)